# How can i create a button in html that changes its text when clicked, and the new text is saved when i enter the page again?

Tags: javascript, html

How can i create a button in html that changes its text when clicked, and the new text is saved when i enter the page again?

```
<input onclick="change()" type="button" value="Mark course as finished" id="myButton1"> </input>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    
    function change() 
    {   var elem = document.getElementById("myButton1");
        if (elem.value=="Mark course as finished") elem.value = "Finished!";
        else elem.value = "Mark course as finished";
    }</script>
```

Comment: Pls read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<p>Click the button to swap the text of the DIV element:</p>
<p><button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button></p>
<div id="myDIV">Hello</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === "Hello") {
    x.innerHTML = "Swapped text!";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Hello";
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi zaigham, no it won't work because i want to change the value inside the button

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).